# How to bind data from datepicker to a regular ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs, jsp, datepicker, bind

jsp page:

```
<label>Script ID:</label> 
        <input name="scriptId" type="text"
            ng-model="selectedScript.scriptId" 
            ng-disabled="true"
            value="{{selectedScript.scriptId}}" 
            /> 


<form>
        <h1>Date Pannel</h1>
        <fieldset>
        Pick a start date:<br>
        <input ng-disabled = "mode =='BROWSE'" type="date" id="datePickerStart" ng-model="parent.startDate" onchange="document.getElementById('datePickerEnd').setAttribute('min', document.getElementById('datePickerStart').value)"><br><br>
        Pick an end date:<br>
        <input ng-disabled = "mode =='BROWSE'" type="date" id="datePickerEnd" ng-model="parent.endDate"  ><br><br>
        <button ng-disabled = "mode =='BROWSE'" ng-click="setDates()" 
        >Set Dates</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.parent = {startDate:''};
$scope.parent = {endDate:''};
$scope.selectedScript.startDate = null;
$scope.selectedScript.endDate = null;


$scope.setDates = function setDates() {
            $scope.selectedScript.startDate = $scope.parent.startDate.getTime();
            $scope.selectedScript.endDate = $scope.parent.endDate.getTime();

            myAppFactory.setDates($scope.selectedScript.startDate, $scope.selectedScript.endDate, $scope.selectedScript.src).success(function(data) {
                $scope.selectedScript.src=data;
            });

        }
```

That's all the code i need to get some stuff done...

Now I have a table on my jsp page...

```
<tr
                ng-repeat="s in scripts
                ng-click="selectScript(s, $index)" 
                ng-class="getSelectedClass(s)">
                <td>{{s.scriptId }}</td>
                <td>{{s.fileName }}</td>
</tr>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.selectScript = function(script, index) {
            if ($scope.mode != 'BROWSE')
                return;
            $scope.parent.startDate = $scope.selectedScript.startDate;  <-- this part
            $scope.parent.endDate.setTime = $scope.selectedScript.endDate; <--and this

            $scope.selectedScript = script;
            $scope.selectedRow = index;
        };
```

When I save the script, the data in the database has startDate and endDate
that works...

My problem is that selectedScript as a model, in the code above, don't has any value in startDate and endDate...it's null (but the fields exist, and the database has the data I need)

But I need somehow to make it possible that parent.startDate and endDate are bound to the selectedScript's startDate and endDate...

Btw, i 1st tried to make the ng-model of the datepicker like selectedScript.startDate, but that didn't work...
Later I found out that the datepicker has it's own scope, and that's causing my problems...at least I believe so.

I just hope that I have made myself clear...
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is because when you retrieve the data from the database, it passes it as a string, which isn't a format that the datepicker can read.

Essentially what you need to do is parse it as a Date attribute, to do this you can do;

```
$scope.parent.startDate = new Date($scope.selectedScript.startDate);
$scope.parent.endDate = new Date($scope.selectedScript.endDate);
```

Use this in the relevant places to parse as a date, or you can set up a watch to do it for you whenever the value is changed;

```
$scope.$watch('parent.startDate', function(startDate){
$scope.parent.startDate = new Date($scope.parent.startDate);
});
```

You can only use $watch for single values, or you can watch the whole object as 'parent'.

Hope it helps!